# File Copying after Closing Application

Tags: multithreading, delphi, file, window, copying

There are several ways to copy files: using `TFileStream`, using `TShFileOpStruct`, `Windows.CopyFile` (at least that's what I've found).
When I start file copying using one of the ways I've mentioned my application freezes (only file copying window is active) and when I close my application, file copying is also canceled.

Is it possible to copy/move files so that the process won't depend on my application?
I mean, how can I start copy/move operation an then close my application and the copying/moving will remain?

Comment: see if this question helps you www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2205746/writing-a-batch-file-for-date-based-file-copying

Answer (score 2):

See @David post, plus..  The one time I can remember where I had a similar requirement, I had to make a backup copy of some data on a network drive on app close.  I just set the CloseAction to caHide in the OnClose handler and so kept the app loaded until the thread running the copy was complete, whereupon it called ExitProcess() to finally die off.

The issue with this simple approach is that the user could attempt to start another copy of the app while the old one was still doing the backups - this caused big problems.  We just added a paragraph in the user manual to cover that, but some better solution, eg. forcing new instances to wait on startup until any old ones have finished, would have been better.  David's solution of running a separate process would seem to be superior in that respect, mod. any 'interference' between the copy and the startup of any new app instance.

Comment: It is possible to stop another instance of the application by a `mutex` or `file mapping`. See here for more details: [Controlling the number of application instances](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/l/aa100703c.htm).

Comment: @LURD yeah - I knew how I could do it, but I was up to my ears in other critical bugs and didn't have time to implement/test it.  We were forced to document this 'feature' instead of fixing it...

Answer (score 1):

for copying to another location even after you have closed your application, you can try this 
using `batch` files...

```
 xcopy d:\from_folder\*.* d:\Tofolder\.
```

this you can execute in a batch file and let you application close, the batch file will continue copying the files to the destination..

you can use shellexecute to

```
 procedure MycopyAndCloseapplication;
    begin
       ShellExecute(handle,'open',pchar('d:\mycopyingBatch.bat'),nil,nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;

    //here than you close your application..

    end;
```

to copy folders which contains more folders inside try this

```
 xcopy d:\sourceFolder d:\destinationFolder /E /Y
```

check these links also

[writing a batch file fordate based file copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205746/writing-a-batch-file-for-date-based-file-copying)

[directo copy batch file command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014354/directo-copy-batch-file-command)

[batch file to copy files to another location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195223/batch-file-to-copy-files-to-another-location)

Answer (score 0):

All of the file copying APIs that I know of execute in the calling process. This means that when you terminate the process, the file copying will be terminated also.

So, in order to ensure that the file copying continues after your application closes, you would need to run the file copy from a different process. You could create a simple process that did the work and pass it command line arguments to specify which files to copy.

If you just want to unfreeze your main application whilst the copy is in progress, then you could create a separate thread to perform the file copy.

Comment: >You could create a simple process that did the work and pass it command line arguments to specify which files to copy.

Could you please give an example how to do it?! Also, when copy/paste files in windows explorer I can close explorer window and file copying will continue. How does it work?

Comment: What part do you have difficulty with? Creating a program? Parsing command line arguments? Using CreateProcess or ShellExecute to start another process?

Comment: Parse command line arguments using `ParamStr`. `ShellExecute` is probably simpler than `CreateProcess`, but either way it's pretty simple.

Comment: As far as I understand I need to create another application that will launch file copying and I should run this (second) application from my 1st application parsing command line arguments. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that would work. As an alternative, you could re-purpose you existing app and just get it to switch behaviour when started with particular arguments.